# How do I migrate data from a db2 backup file to ms sql server database?

Tags: ssis, db2, etl, iseries-navigator

I have a db2 backup file and a windows environment with sql server 2019. I need to migrate the data from db2 to sql server. I went through various solutions and all requires connection to IBM Iseries system.
Is there any way to achieve this without connection to IBM i series system with just db2 backup file? Or how do i install a db2 database server in my windows so that i can use that to restore db2 backup and then use it to migrate to sql database using SSIS? I have no experience with db2 or iseries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows (aka Db2 for LUW) and Db2 for IBM i (aka Db2 for iSeries) are different products running on different operating systems.
You can't use backup files from Db2 for IBM i to restore the information from it to Db2 for LUW, and you can't install Db2 for IBM i on your Windows system.

So, there is no way to use this backup file without Db2 for IBM i.

Comment: is it a backup or an export ? what is the format, ixf ?

Answer (score 0):

you can ask iSeries (AS400) sysadmin to do a CSV export of the tables. after you can import the CSV into your mysql

Comment: Would that be better or getting the iSeries connection details and using SSIS to export the data to sql using ODBC ? My data is large , minimum 300 thousand rows in each table. Any ideas on this?